# google_project_services.default: Error updating services: googleapi

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, terraform-provider-gcp

The following occurs when running `Terraform Apply`. I am creating a number of BigQuery datasets through Terraform.

`google_project_services.default: Error updating services: googleapi: Error 503: The service(s) ["bigquery.googleapis.com"] are still being enabled for project [PROJECT_NAME]. This isn't a real API error, this is just eventual consistency.`

Answer (score 0):

[Error temporarily resolved here](https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-google/issues/4590)